# Stop Safari from opening FaceTime when a site contains a phone number

Tags: safari, mojave, facetime

When navigating with Safari to some sites that have phone numbers, Safari diligently opens FaceTime when I click on a phone number. Is there a way to prevent this?

I am currently tempted to delete the FaceTime app from the Applications folder, but I hope there is a less drastic way to do this.

**more info** : Both Chrome and Firefox propose the option to 'open FT' or cancel. I was looking for a similar setting in Safari.

Comment: That will only happen when you have 2 things setup and one of them is that you either click on a phone number or hover over it and attempt to make a phone call.  Are you doing this or are you saying **any** page with a phone number displayed causes FT to open?

Comment: my bad ... when i click on the phone  number.  I just dont want FT to open, under any circumstance.

Comment: What do you want (or expect) to happen when you click a phone number?

Comment: @IconDaemon nothing.

Comment: Then why do you click on the phone number?

Comment: @IconDaemon : am currently developing , i need exclusive use of the camera. This was part of a test.

Comment: That would have been be good information to know from the start!

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not 100% certain on this*

[image: FaceTime menu]

If you uncheck "Calls from iPhone"
[image: faceTime preferences]

in FaceTime Preferences, this should stop happening.

Comment: When I open FT, there are no preferences available. Probably because i did not provide an iCloud/appleID.   I guess i'll be down to nuking the FT App after all.  In case you wonder, i cant/wont/dont want an iCloud binding on my dev box , which will be causing havoc with my `multiple` appleID's and my personal appleID.

Comment: huh... is it just greyed out?

Comment: oh, can you send an example url so I can test this? I don't run across phone numbers in websites that often...

Comment: it does make sense that the "Calls from iPhone" wouldn't be there without connecting it to your Apple ID, so maybe I'll just delete this answer...

Comment: actually it does not ... but the answer is still useful. I think that is a flaw in the design of FT.  Yes, greyed out, nada, nil, not available Preferences.  There is a phone number at the top right hand corner of https://www.crea-med.ca